# Error when opening Office 2010 documents from Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office-2010

I am getting an error when i create new Document from **Sharepoint 2010**, each time it open Microsoft word and after loading it alerts me a message

> "Could not open
>   'http://SharePointServer/../[DocumentLibrary]/Forms/template.dotx'"

So what could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: How are you opening the documents?

Comment: Did you already check if the according MIME type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template` is added to your IIS website configuration?

Comment: How can i check this option from IIS ?

Comment: normally .. i open the documents from Document Library > Documents section in the ribbon > and create new Document

Comment: Same issue with me....Only happens when creating new document, does not happen for opening existing docs...